# Function pointer within array within struct

Tags: c, function-pointers

I am trying to create and call a function pointer, however when I try and call the function pointer my program crashes and Valgrind gives me an error.

The function pointer within the struct is defined as:

```
    BOOLEAN (*function)(int * input_int);
```

and then I am calling it as:

```
array[0].function(input);
```

(where input is an int)

When I call it though I get an error in Valgrind, a jump to an invalid address. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

My bad here is how my dummy function is defined:

```
array[0].function = &dummy_function;
BOOLEAN dummy_function(int * input_int)
{
    if(input_int == 0)
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's very hard to say.

Comment: How is `dummy_function` declared?

Comment: Yes, please update with the body of `dummy_function` or at least the declaration

Comment: You are apparently using the pointer notation incorrectly.

Comment: How is `array` declared?

Comment: Beat me by 21s!-) @Kevin

Comment: 1. If you indent properly, you'll see that your function doesn't return a value unless you pass it 0, which leads to undefined behavior. 2. Do you really mean to use an `int *` there? Hint: probably not.

Comment: Are you making the `array[0].function = &dummy_function` assignment *before* you define or declare the `dummy_function`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Would it compile then?

Comment: In C you should always define or declare function before you use them, otherwise the compiler will guess, and in your case it might be that the compiler guesses badly. Always build with as many warnings enabled as possible, and read those compiler warnings carefully and try to fix the root cause of the warnings.

Comment: Did you print %p the function pointer at the point you are calling it to verify it is still the same as &dummy_function?   Did you add a signature value to your structure when initialized and verify that it is still before referencing the contents of the structure?

Comment: Many possibilities already sorted out. My bet is now on array[0] being invalid. Is array declared as having at least one element? For example as array[1]?

Comment: If input in the calling statement is indeed `int`, than this statement is incorrect as well, because your function expects a pointer to int, it should be `array[0].function(&input)`. So to sum it up. Here are a lot of undefined behaviours and it is a badly stated question.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that the fragments of code shown here either will not compile or are not the same as those that trigger the error or both. Please provide an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, or this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

input shouldn't be integer but integer pointer 
Instead of:

```
array[0].function(input);
```

Try:

```
 array[0].function(&input);
```

also use

```
 array[0].function = dummy_function;
```

Comment: They're identical in C, and the former should be preferred.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.